# CSS scrollbar-gutter

Tags: scrollbar, customizing, gutter

Trying to see results on firefox with property scrollbar-gutter but didnt get answer.

Trying to see results on firefox with property scrollbar-gutter with but didnt get answer. the gap between content and scrollbar changes on chrome but not work on firefox!